# Jenkins: Moving TCL script to a slave job

Tags: jenkins, tcl

I have move a Jenkins job from a Windows based Master to a system with a Linux Master and Windows slave.  In fact, the system that was the master is now the slave, using Swarm.  Most of my jobs work fine, but I have a problem executing a tcl script on the slave.  I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Tcl execution failed: couldn't change working directory to "C:\slave2Workspace\workspace\SDB Projects\VE03FW": no such file or directory
Archiving artifacts
Finished: FAILURE
```

The path certainly exists on the slave.  This gives me the impression that the tcl script is executing on the master even though the job is sent to the slave.

How can I get the script to execute on the slave?  It does execute when run as the master in the "run tcl script" as the build step.  The job configuration was copied from the Windows master to the new Linux master.

Comment: Like the error message says, there's no directory `C:\slave2Workspace\workspace\SDB Projects\VE03FW` on the slave system, so the slave can't `cd` into it. No idea what the wider significance of that is.

Comment: But there is such a directory, since all of the other artifacts do come from that directory.  I can log onto the slave system and see the specific directory.  The other thing is that I do not specify this path anywhere in the job configuration, the system "deduces" the path itself.

Comment: If I move the script into a file, and execute the script on the slave (with a suitable tcl interperter) as a step in a Windows Batch File stage, the function works.  This is crude, but effective.  If anyone thinks this is an actual answer, please chime in.